# Core Data in Singleton class

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, core-data, singleton

What I have so far is a JSON file that I read inside the singleton. I use the singleton to be able to share data between different controllers.

Now I have to implement Core Data; I was wondering if I'm supposed to delete the singleton and just use the core data, or if I can implement it within the singleton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton works very well for Core Data.
Simply move all the methods from App Delegate to your singleton class and call them from there.